# Projectile trajectory horizontal travel equation

Tags: derivatives, physics, projectile-motion

Working on a system for a game, I'm having a hard time figuring out a reasonable way to predict a trajectory of a projectile.

Variables: 
$a$ - angle in radians 
$v$ - velocity 
$t$ - time 
$y$ - height 
$g$ - gravity

$$y=\sin(a)vt -\frac{g}{2} t^2$$

I’ve got a fairly simple way to solve for $y$ and $x$ parameters at any given time, but I’m primarily struggling with solving time for a specific $x$ and $y$.

The goal is to be able to predict when a projectile touches the ground (what time) and estimate range or distance ($x$) of how far the projectile will have traveled horizontally by then.

I get that I need to solve $t$ for $y=0$ but I’m really trying to figure out how I can plug all this into one equation I can then translate into code. Not sure if I’m thinking about this all wrong, but any help is really appreciated!

The closest I’ve come to is this:

$$t=\frac{v\sin(a) -\sqrt{v^2\sin^2(a)-2gy}}{g}$$
where $g\ne 0$.

Comment: What is wrong with solving for $t$ when $y = 0$? Are you unsure of how to do that?

Comment: Regardless, if you're having trouble, see the wiki - [projectile motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion)

Comment: Yup, not sure, I'd know how to practically come up to an answer, but not sure how to put into tangible steps I can translate into code. Using tools like desmos for example, helped and makes it super easy but feels like I'm cheating and skipping steps without the underlying understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Looks helpful

Comment: The first minus sign in your solution should be $\pm$, like this: $t=\frac{v\sin(a) \pm\sqrt{v^2\sin^2(a)-2gy}}{g}$. Plugging in $y=0$ and simplifying, you have two possible values. One is $t=0$ (because $y=0$ at the start of the trajectory) and the other is the answer.